# re.findall() returning empty tuples

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a regex '[-]*[0-9]*,\s*[0-9]*(?!(km)|(Km)|(metres?)|(miles?)|(m)|(mi))'.

When I use this on regexr.com it matches '558,21' and other patterns.

but if I am using re.findall() in python

`re.findall( '[-]*[0-9]*,\s*[0-9]*(?!(km)|(Km)|(metres?)|(miles?)|(m)|(mi))' , text)`

it is returning me this as the output even though '558,21' is present in text variable:

`[('', '', '', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', '', '', '')]`

What might be the reason for it?

Comment: Remove all the capturing groups. You may also make sure you match at least 1 digit, use `+` with some `[0-9]`, i.e. `[0-9]*,\s*[0-9]*` => `[0-9]+(?:,\s*[0-9]+)?`

Comment: But then how will I implement the negative lookahead?

Comment: What is the problem with `(?!km|Km|metres?|miles?|m|mi)`? ``(?![kK]m|metres?|miles?|mi?)`` is a bit better though

Comment: yeah man. It solves the problem . Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: `r'(?i)-?[0-9]+(?:,\s*[0-9]+)?(?!\s*(?:km|metres?|miles?|mi?)\b)'` might be a better pattern, but the main point is the capturing groups always create items in the list of tuples